# Error when deleting user information in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to integrate delete account functionality, but am running into an error. I believe I have found out the solution to the problem but am looking for input on an alternative solution as mine is unsafe.

here is my delete account function

```
func deleteAccount()
{
    let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    let uid = user!.uid

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    user?.deleteWithCompletion({ (error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            //error occurred during deletion
            print(error)
        }
        else
        {
            print("Account deleted")

            //account deleted, remove the user data and segue back
            let removedRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL("https://myURL.com/users/\(uid)")

            //set nil to that value to delete it
            removedRef.setValue(nil)
        }
    })
}
```

The error I am getting is removeValue failed: permission_denied. I'm assuming this is due to the fact that I delete my user prior to deleting the associated user information. However, if I were to move the deletion code outside of the closure block, if an error occurs then all of the user's information gets deleted regardless.

I'm looking to improve on this deletion method.

Comment: Not positive, but you should probably log out and make your delete function take a user as a parameter.

Comment: A few things. For a user to be deleted they must have signed in recently. You may want to re-authenticate them. That's probably not this issue but wanted to mention it. Second thing is that you may have Rules in place preventing the deleting of the data from the /users node. That could also be coupled with the order of operations; you may want to delete the user from the /users node first and then delete the account from Firebase upon success. Oh, and by default with v3, you must be authenticated to read/write so again, check your Rules.

Comment: Thanks Jay, the rules did contain both read and write capabilities, so that is not an issue. I ended up just moving the removedReg.setValue and removedRef to above the closure block to achieve the desired functionality. As a follow up, if the user must be logged in to delete their account, must I still re-authenticate? Thanks.